# In Jenkins build flow plugin, terminate all parallel jobs if one of them failed

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, jenkins

We are using the jenkins build flow plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) to run our test cases by dividing them into small sub test cases and test them in parallel.

The current problem is even one of the job fails, the other parallel jobs and the hosting flow job will continue running, which is a big waste of resources.

I checked the doc there is no place to control the jobs inside the parallel {}. Any ideas how to deal with that?

Comment: Unbelievable. This is still [not resolved](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35663).

Answer (score 1):

Looking [at the code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-flow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/cloudbees/plugins/flow/FlowDSL.groovy), I don't see a way to achieve that. I would ask the user mailing list for help.

Answer (score -1):

I am thinking to use Guard / Rescue imbedded in Parallel to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `failFast: true` within `parallel` block would cause the build to fail as soon as one of the parallel nodes fails.

You can view [this](https://github.com/kmadel/jenkins-workflow-examples/blob/master/failFast.groovy#L9) as an example.